# flex++ switchstream

Tags: bison, lex, flex++

I'm trying to write a parser using flex++ and bison. I need the parser to be able to read from a file and write a new file in output.

I have an yyFlexLexer instantiated as follows:

```
yyFlexLexer lexer;
```

and I use it:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::istream* in_file = new std::ifstream(argv[1])
    std::ostream* out_file = new std::ofstream(argv[2])
    lexer.switch_streams(in_file, out_file);
    yyparse();
    return 0;
}
```

If I run:

```
./executable foo bar
```

the parser correctly read the file foo (I can see it making some printing in bison rules) but at the end I found only an empty file called "bar" without anything in it.

I have also tried to do this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::istream* in_file = new std::ifstream(argv[1])
    std::ostream* out_file = new std::ofstream(argv[2])
    lexer.switch_streams(in_file, out_file);
    while(lexer.yylex())
    ;
    return 0;
}
```

but it does the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

You need the parser's actions (in your `.y` file) to build some abstract syntax tree of the parsed input, and you need some routine to pretty print that tree to the output.

`flex` and `bison` do only the parsing (which is not much). You should do the rest.

I don't understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: I realized all rules for my syntax. I was thinking that the out_file passed to the yyFlexLexer was used by the parser to print the output. If not, I don't understand for what is used the output stream passed to the method switch_streams.

Comment: Documentation http://flex.sourceforge.net/manual/Cxx.html says that "virtual void switch_streams(istream* new_in = 0, ostream* new_out = 0)
reassigns yyin to new_in (if non-null) and yyout to new_out (if non-null), deleting the previous input buffer if yyin is reassigned.". But I think you don't understand how to use Flex and Bison. Please explain your overall goal.

Comment: I explain better the question. I have already realized the parser. It works fine while I print the output to stdout (the complete output obtained at the end of the execution of all rules). I was only supposing that the method switch_stream is used to redirect the output from the stdout to a custom stream. At this moment I'm also able to write to a custom stream writing on it in my terminal rule.

Reading the documentaion it seems to me that the function will do what I think but evidently not.